# Error Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController] when trying to set up authentication in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am trying to update an old (5.2) laravel installation to the newest one (9.2) and most is working except the authentication part.

I already installed laravel/ui, I have an authentication middleware, route and controller but for some reason I get:

```
Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController].
```

My Authenticate.php middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

My route in web.php :

```
Route::get('/login', 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController')->name('login');
```

And my AuthController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Topsite\Dataroom\Models\LogEntry;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * The custom login view.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $loginView = 'pages.login';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Send the response after the user was authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  bool $throttles
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function handleUserWasAuthenticated(Request $request, $throttles)
    {
        if ($throttles) {
            $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
        }

        if (method_exists($this, 'authenticated')) {
            return $this->authenticated($request, Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->user());
        }

        LogEntry::create([
            'account_id' => Auth::id(),
            'message' => 'Ingelogd'
        ]);

        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
}
```

I thought maybe I need to set a method in the route so I changed the route to:

```
Route::get('/login', 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@handleUserWasAuthenticated')->name('login');
```

But this gives:

Too few arguments to function `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController::handleUserWasAuthenticated(), 1 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\dataroom.website.nl.test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 2 expected`

I think the `$throttles` variable is empty but what needs to be passed there? Or maybe I am thinking wrong alltogether and the fix is something else?

Comment: I would delete everything a do a `ui:auth` to have a clean auth scaffolding, if there is nothing special in those controllers, the AuthController is called RegisterController now for example, i guess it's 5.1 auth scaffolding, not really worth keeping

Comment: @Lk77 Yeah that's probably a better solution, thanks.